# Efficient dictionary key intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say, for example, we have the following dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {a:b, b:c}
dict2 = {b:c, c:d}
```

What is the most efficient way of intersecting the keys of both dictionaries?

Of course, one can use `set(dict1.keys()).intersection(set(dict2.keys()))`, but I assume converting the dictionary to a set first is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 9):

`keys` is a view and has the intersection operator

```
dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
```

Or simply

```
dict1.keys() & dict2
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dict.keys()` [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) supports set operations:

```
dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()  # equivalent to set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
```

However, for smaller dictionaries using a set will probably be faster:

```
In [1]: dict1 = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

In [2]: dict2 = {'b': 'c', 'c': 'd'}

In [3]: %timeit dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
448 ns ± 1.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)    

In [4]: %timeit set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
330 ns ± 0.602 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Note that [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) accepts *any iterable* as an argument, so you can just pass `dict2` to it. Also, no need to call `dict1.keys()`as a `dict` object by default iterates over its keys.